# Connecting OneDrive data to Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, sharepoint, onedrive, azure-databricks

I have created an Azure Databricks cluster and would like to connect to a SharePoint folder to read and upload files. I cannot seem to find any solution to this. Please advise.

Comment: Hello, did you reach an answer to this?

Comment: I found this and it seems promise. https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/onedrive-jdbc-azure-databricks.rst.